# How to build a stacked bar chart overlay in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

Does anyone know how to have this stacked bar chart in highcharts?

[image: stacked column bar chart]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements you can use `normal` or `percent` stacking option for three stacked series. The rest of the series goes without stacking.

```
  series: [{
      stacking: 'normal',
      data: [2]
    }, {
      stacking: 'normal',
      data: [2]
    },
    {
      stacking: 'normal',
      data: [4]
    },
    {
      data: [8]
    },
    {
      data: [8]
    }
  ]
```

The other options that you will need are formatting `series.dataLabels` and `xAxis.labels`.

**Demo that you can base on:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sLgyhoz9/

**API References:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bar.stacking
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bar.dataLabels.formatter
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter